# Solving the heat equation by FEniCS

Tags: python, fenics

I am facing a coding error in FEniCS when I run the heat equation code it’s fail with,

`error = np.abs(u_e.vector().array() - u.vector().array())
AttributeError: 'dolfin.cpp.la.PETScVector' object has no attribute 'array’`

I believe the idea is to calculate the difference between u and the exact solution for each time level  and put them in array then we going to take the maxium value.(if not, correct me please!)

the Original code for computing the error is

```
u_e = interpolate(u_D, V)
error = np.abs(u_e.vector().array() - u.vector().array()).max()
print('t = %.2f: error = %.3g' % (t, error))
```

Where u_D is the boundary condition.

I am not sure how I can make it works so any advice from you would appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found out the answer and I would like to share it with you, just in case any one interested. array() was replaced with get_local().

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? It solved my problem!

Comment: Thanks @roby. I had similar error, replacing array() with get_local() solved my problem too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment of roby, `array()` has been replaced by `get_local()`. So in lines 62-65 of the [third fenics tutorial](https://github.com/hplgit/fenics-tutorial/blob/master/pub/python/vol1/ft03_heat.py), the following works:

```
    # Compute error at vertices
    u_e = interpolate(u_D, V)
    error = np.abs(u_e.vector().get_local() - u.vector().get_local()).max()
    print('t = %.2f: error = %.3g' % (t, error))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to employ the conversion from the `numpy` module, in case you desire a lighter notation:

```
u_v = numpy.array(u.vector())
```

Or if you prefer to mantain the structure of the original variable

```
u_v = u.vector()
```

I prefer the first one since I am more confortable with a MatLab-style usage of vectors.